# How to let the status bar color above the navigation view change when you open it

Tags: android, xml

I have created a navigation viewer but when you open it the color in the status bar doesn't change. Here is what happens:
[image: no color change]

and this is what I want as the result:
[image: color change]

You see that in the first image the status bar stayed the same and in the second image it changed. The xml code that I have for this now is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".UI.Story.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0px"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer"
            app:menu="@menu/menu" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Could someone please help me and point out where I am going wrong

Update:

It seems that when I am using this in styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

It works but when I change Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar to Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar it doesn't

Comment: you have to make the status bar translucent

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code in the past:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    //make translucent statusBar on kitkat devices
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, true);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    //make fully Android Transparent Status bar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}

public static void setWindowFlag(Activity activity, final int bits, boolean on) {
    Window win = activity.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    if (on) {
        winParams.flags |= bits;
    } else {
        winParams.flags &= ~bits;
    }
    win.setAttributes(winParams);
}
```

([source](https://learnpainless.com/android/material/make-fully-android-transparent-status-bar))